# Significance of 1 and 2 while reverting merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I came across a situation, where I need to revert one of my merge commit in git. I used the following command:

```
git revert -m 1 [merge commit id]
```

Now git provides one more option for the above command as below:

```
git revert -m 2 [merge commit id]
```

I did not get the difference between **1 and 2**

References Used: https://www.christianengvall.se/undo-pushed-merge-git/

Comment: A merge commit has mostly 2 parents, and the number indicates to with parent you want to revert

Answer (score 1):

The git revert documentation provides the syntax like

```
git revert [--[no-]edit] [-n] [-m parent-number] [-s] [-S[<keyid>]] <commit>…​
```

So the number after `-m` here represents the parent number

A merge commit may have two parents say consider an example that your current hash is `0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3`

and has two parents

```
df1acf5f54426d30f12c6b4558c3dd922297aae3
e19b912404ffd3c153ccac3072dbf22396896d2a

git revert -m 2 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3
```

will revert to `e19b912404ffd3c153ccac3072dbf22396896d2a`

**[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)**

Answer (score 0):

A git repository is just a tree of commits. A merge commit is just a commit that has two (or more) parents.

If you revert a commit with a single parent, you're just reversing the changes introduced by that commit.

If you're reverting a merge commit, however, you need to revert all the changes from the branch that you merged in. However, there's no real concept of which branch was merged to which - you just have the parents of the commit, and `-m` tells git which parent you want to revert *to* (ie. undo the changes introduced from the other parent)

See the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert--mparent-number